# DNN - Get date a module was upload

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7

I need to show a message when a user's last login was before the last time we update a module.

I can get the users last login using a cookie (if need be) but I can't seem to find a way of extracting the date a module was last updated/uploaded.

I am able to create a moduelINfo object which has some date fields but their all MinValue
is there a way of either:
1) Retrieving the date a module was uploaded
2) Automatically saving the date as a portal/moduleSetting when we upload or compile the module (ChrisToc)
3) Some other means of testing whether a user's last visit was before the last update.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably end up having to do this by looking directly at the Database, in the DESKTOPMODULES table, to see when the LastModifiedOnDate column is updated for the module in question. I don't know that DNN keeps track of module versions like it does with the platform itself (DNN uses the Versions table)

Comment: YEp, thats what I ended up doing - the field only updates when you upload the installation zip, so it works perfectly for our purposes.

Comment: there was a ModuleInfo object, but when populated with ModuleID and TabI - most of the data was null